# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() since updating my Customizr theme

Tags: php, wordpress, invalid-argument

I just updated my Customizr child theme and I'm getting the following error on my dashboard:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/beaufort/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/class-fire-utils.php on line 653

This is what is on line 653:

```
foreach ( $_font_groups as $_group_slug => $_font_list ) {
```

and this is what follows:

```
 if ( 'list' == $_what ) {
          $_to_return[$_group_slug] = array();
          $_to_return[$_group_slug]['list'] = array();
          $_to_return[$_group_slug]['name'] = $_font_list['name'];
        }
```

I am clueless when it comes to php so your help would be much appreicated!

Many thanks

```
    /**
    * @return an array of font name / code OR a string of the font css code
    * @parameter string name or google compliant suffix for href link
    *
    * @package Customizr
    * @since Customizr 3.2.9
    */
    function tc_get_font( $_what = 'list' , $_requested = null ) {
      $_to_return = ( 'list' == $_what ) ? array() : false;
      $_font_groups = apply_filters(
        'tc_font_pairs',
        TC_init::$instance -> font_pairs
      );
      foreach ( $_font_groups as $_group_slug => $_font_list ) {
        if ( 'list' == $_what ) {
          $_to_return[$_group_slug] = array();
          $_to_return[$_group_slug]['list'] = array();
          $_to_return[$_group_slug]['name'] = $_font_list['name'];
        }

        foreach ( $_font_list['list'] as $slug => $data ) {
          switch ($_requested) {
            case 'name':
              if ( 'list' == $_what )
                $_to_return[$_group_slug]['list'][$slug] =  $data[0];
            break;

            case 'code':
              if ( 'list' == $_what )
                $_to_return[$_group_slug]['list'][$slug] =  $data[1];
            break;

            default:
              if ( 'list' == $_what )
                $_to_return[$_group_slug]['list'][$slug] = $data;
              else if ( $slug == $_requested ) {
                  return $data[1];
              }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return $_to_return;
    }
```

Comment: Means that `$_font_groups` isn't an array!

Comment: You have to use an array and or make sure it is an array

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123, this is all very new to me. Are you able to advise how I do that? Thank you

Comment: Show us your full script

Comment: Make a past bin an post the link

Comment: Hi @Rizier123 were you able to take a look? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before line 653 add `if (is_array($_font_groups)) {`
Then, add a closing bracket `}` above `return $_to_return;`